# Dynamically loading the layout

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, onclick

In my app, i am loading a layout dynamically with text views ,on a button's onclick event. when i click the button for the first time , i got my layout with text views. when i click it again ,it should display the layout again. but its showing error. my code is

```
    private OnClickListener some_name = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
LinearLayout my_list_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_list_layout);
        my_list_layout.setOrientation(1);
        my_list_layout.setId(50);
        my_textview = new TextView[length];

        for(int i=0; i<length ; i++)
            {
                my_textview[i]= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                my_textview[i].setText("sample text");
                my_textview[i].setId(i);

                if(i==0)
                    {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams my_textviewparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        my_textviewparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,my_list_layout.getId());
                        my_list_layout.addView(my_textview[i],my_textviewparams);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams my_textviewparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        my_textviewparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,my_textview[i-1].getId());
                        my_list_layout.addView(my_textview[i],my_textviewparams);
                    }
    }
    }
```

and my error log is

[image]

quick response is needed. anyone tell me, what is my wrong in coding, or what changes i have to do for my requirement?

Comment: what is the line 230 in the code

Comment: my_list_layout.setOrientation(1);
above is the 230th line

Comment: what is my_list_content_textview?

Comment: i made changes scorpion. now u look into code

Comment: show your xml also and change LinearLayout code in to onCreate() method..

Comment: <LinearLayout 
              android:id="@+id/my_list_layout"
           android:background="#67300f"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent">
          </LinearLayout>
above is my xml. and i want the code in onclick only. i am dispalying this linear layout in an activity during the button lick.

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.my_list_layout)` does not find anything. Save the View in a member variable

Comment: yeah i have tried that too.. no result... any other way???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.Here while i was doing first time the btn click, the child view will added to my parent view dynamically.

During the second click the i removed previously added child from my parent view and added the new child. So this will updates my content and displays clearly every time when I click the btn.

I got error in removing the views from my child, now I clear the error by assigning some variables for identifying btn click, whether user clicks it for first time or not. thank you all for your time here and for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove this line:

```
my_list_layout.setId(50);
```

because once you set the id to 50, and again when you click the `Button`, the `LinearLayout` is `null` because you call `findViewById(R.id. my_list_layout);` its id has been changed to 50.

Cheers!

Comment: i have removed that line also. still same problem.

Comment: i am adding this linear layout to a scroll view. so during the second click on the button, whether i have to remove the first layout and then add the layout again?